# Palo Alto Authentication through Postman

Tags: postman

how do we use authentication which has VIP token keeps changing every 30 sec along with password to authorize network devices ?

but when i run api below call , i'm getting invalid cred error...

**API CALL** -> {{url}}/api/?type=keygen&user={{username}}&password={{password}}{{token}}

**Error->**

```
<response status = 'error' code = '403'>
    <result>
        <msg>Invalid Credential</msg>
    </result>
</response>
```

also defined appropriate Params for env variable values in Postman..

Comment: Can you include a link to the API specification.